# how to generate html with javascript method and object parameter

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, javascript-objects

I'm generating a link in my javascript

ex. `<a href="#" onClick="openContactDetailPage('+JSON.stringify(contact)+')">'+ formattedName + '</a>`

However, the quotes aren't escaped in the object so it doesn't really work.

The original link I had was :

`<a href="#" onClick="openContactDetailPage('+contact+')">'+ formattedName + '</a><`

This just shows the [Object] text not the actual object. I feel like there has to be an easy solution for this I just can't seem to find it.

UPDATE: fixed links to be less generic

Comment: what is `object` supposed to be?  Are you trying to execute a method on the `object`?  if not, what is `methodName` supposed to do?

Comment: @mr rogers I'm trying to pass the object to the method methodName. The object is a Contact with name,ID etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contacts = {one:'John', two: 'Anne'};  
    for (var prop in contacts) {
        var $anchor = $('<a href=""></a>').text(prop)
        .click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            method({hi:'hi'});
        });
        $('#contacts').append($anchor).append('<br/>');
    }
});

function method(myObject){

    var $response = $('#response');

    for (var prop in myObject) {
        $response.append(prop).append('<br/>');
    }
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrodriguezr/7w3gC/1/)

Comment: I'm generating the href in my javascript dynamically so its not there when the DOM loads. Its basically generating a list of contacts and when the user clicks on one i want to load the detail page for that contact by passing the selected contact object to the method to render it

Answer (score 0):

```
'<a href="#" onclick="methodName('+JSON.stringify(object)+');">Click here</a>'
```

As you are doing in javascript, it should be string. So you can do like this.

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/embkay06/8ha5U/)

Comment: Sorry, this is actually what I have, I updated my question (long day). The issue is the stringify isn't escaping characters so when you see the link this generates it looks like this : `onclick="methodName({"id":"001",..` and complains about an invalid `{` character.